# Qt Resource System and MSVC C1060

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I faced the problem of out of space in the heap when compiling qrc file.
Listing of qrc file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>package.lpgk</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

So, as you see, qrc file contains one file (35Mb) and I still have a compiler error C1060.

In Windows Task Manager (taskmgr.exe) I see, what compiler uses around 2Gb RAM (it's all available memory at moment), and swapping.

Specifying compiller options like /Zm2000 do not help.
I uses MSVC 2010 version.

Comment: I doubt the resource is the reason the compiler is using 2GB RAM. And a qrc file is compiled using rcc, not MSVC. What are you compiling and how?

Comment: rcc creates a .cpp source file, perhaps this file has exceeded file size limits set by MSVC, check to see if you can compile the that file on its own. If your resource file is called xxxx.qrc, look under Generated Files for a file called qrc_xxxx.cpp for the output that rcc generates

Comment: Yes, the file weighs 185 mb. It contains statice const unsigned char qt_resource_data [] = {...}  with the hex data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, you can use an external binary resources file.
Create it by:

```
rcc -binary myresource.qrc -o myresource.rcc
```

Than load in application

```
QResource::registerResource("/path/to/myresource.rcc");
```

There are no VS compiler using for this process, and no error raised.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still facing this issue, there are bug reports regarding it [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55293) and [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50468). The easy solution is to append `resources_big` to your project `CONFIG` (i.e. *.pro* file) like this:

```
CONFIG += c++17 resources_big
```

Answer (score 1):

We are experiencing the same problem after moving to Visual Studio 2013. On VS 2010, for both 32- and 64-bit Windows, there's no problem. On VS 2013, we were able to fix the 64-bit build by disabling multi-processor compilation for the problem module, but that didn't fix the 32-bit build. The suggestion to upgrade to the newest version is actually what caused the problem in our case, so I wouldn't necessarily expect that to fix the problem, nor is it always possible to do that.

Our generated .cpp is only 45 MB, so it's substantially smaller than the original poster's example. At this point, my approach will likely be to split the .qrc file into several smaller files. We're embedding a number of font files, so I can do that. If the problem is caused by a single large resource (such as a video, for example), then splitting it won't work. I know this isn't a definitive answer, but hopefully the additional information will help arrive at a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Workaround for this : update MSVC Compiler to newest version (11.00.50727.1) aka 2012
For compilation that file (185Mb) compiler uses 11-12 Gb of memory (terribly slow on my machine with 4Gb RAM)